# Geoserver 2.1.3 no GetFeatureInfo-Response when multiple Features found on same location within same layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have a Geoserver postgis layer with multiple point features on the same location. GetFeatureInfo returns results when only one feature is found.

But Geoserver returns nothing (empty html) when several Features with different can be found. However, Geoserver's log does not note any errors.

Features have a unique gid which is primary key in the underlying postgis table.

Here is the content-section of the freemarkers template:

```
<div style="font-family: Arial;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
<#list features as feature>
  <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
    <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
      <#if attribute.name == "info_name">
        <#assign info_name = attribute.value>
      </#if>
      <#if attribute.name == "info_adr1">
        <#assign info_adr1 = attribute.value>

      </#if>
      <#if attribute.name == "info_adr2">
        <#assign info_adr2 = attribute.value>

      </#if>
      <#if attribute.name == "info_tel">
        <#assign info_tel = attribute.value>
      </#if>
      <#if attribute.name == "info_kategorie">
        <#assign info_kategorie = attribute.value>
      </#if>
       <#if attribute.name == "description">
        <#assign description = attribute.value>
       </#if>
      <#if attribute.name == "info_url">
        <#assign info_url = attribute.value>
        <#if (info_url!?length > 0)>
            <#assign link = "<a href=\"http://${info_url}\" target=\"_blank\">Homepage</a>">
        </#if>
      </#if>
    </#if>
  </#list>
<b><h2>${info_name}</h2></b>
<#if (info_adr1!?length >0)>
    ${info_adr1}  <br />
</#if>
<#if (info_adr2!?length >0)>
    ${info_adr2}  <br />    
</#if>
<#if (info_tel!?length >0) >
    ${info_tel} <br />
</#if>
<#if (description!?length > 0) >
    ${description}  <br />
</#if>
<#if (link!?length > 0) >
    Link: ${link}   
</#if>      
</#list>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a custom freemarkers template? If yes what happens when you don't use it, or use a different template? Do you get a different result if you change your layer's symbology?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure GetFeaturInfo can return more than one feature, the GeoServer preview returns up to 50 features located in the vicinity of where you clicked.

Comment: Yes it can, but then the request must include the feature_count parameter. If it is missing the feature_count defaults to 1. However, it does not explain why no info at all is returned. Info from one feature is what should happen.